# Save relationship ID in parent class of one to one mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two simple classes called Student and Location

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonProperty("location")
    private Location location;


    /* Getters and Setters */

}

@Entity
public class Location {

    private Integer id;
    private String locationName;
    private String street;
    private String postalCode;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;


    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

Currently the schema is such that the student's `id` is stored in the location table but logically `Location` is independent of the `Student` entity. Its the `Student` that should have the `Location` entity's id

Based on all the examples I have seen online, its the child class in my case `Location` that ends up having the mapping relationship. I tried reversing the `mappedby` attribute by setting it on the `private Student student;` variable but it does not seem to create that column in the database.

The JSON I get in the REST request is structured in the following way:

```
"students": [
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "location": {
                "id": "5678", 
                "locationName": "St.Mary",
                "street": "Wellington St",
                "postalCode": "41298"
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        /* Can have more students here */
    ]
```

So DB wise this is what I want the schema to look like:

```
students
id name location_id

locations
id location_name street postal_code
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I would really appreciate some help on this as I have been stuck with this problem for a while

Answer (score 0):

`Location` is the reference table. A reference table should be mapped with `@ManyToOne` annotation. `Location` can be eagerly loaded, if it makes working with data more simply. But I prefer a lazy approach by default. Also `@JoinColumn` is not necessary (it is used by default). But it makes a mapping more clear and can be used to specify a join column name. Also `@ForeignKey` annotation can be used to specify a foreign key constraint name.

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column 
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Location location;

}

@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String locationName;

}
```

Comment: ManyToOne makes a lot sense. I guess I wasn't thinking clearly as I was obsessed with reversing one to one mapping.